# How to combine graphics inside a For loop?

Tags: graphics

How can I combine graphics inside a For loop? For example, the following yields a red rectangle:

```
Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 3}]}]
```

But how can I get a long line of them? The following code shows what I would like to do, even if it does not work!

```
For[i = 1, i < 11, i++, 
 Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{3 i, 0}, {3 i + 1, 3}]}]]
```

Comment: Why is this question off-topic? The template reason cites either a "simple mistake" or place in the documentation. What mistake or what place?

Answer (score 2):

Oh well...having puzzled over this for about half an hour, as soon as I post the question I realise how to answer it! But I will leave this here in the hope that it helps other people.

The solution I found is to use Table, like this:

```
myrectangles = Table[{Red, Rectangle[{3 i, 0}, {3 i + 1, 3}]}, {i, 1, 10}];
Graphics[myrectangles]
```

Comment: I might try: Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{3 #, 0}, {3 # + 1, 3}]} & /@ Range[10]]